# get sub OUs description within a given OU

Tags: list, powershell, directory, ou

Is there any simple way of getting a list of all the OUs located one level under a given OU?

i.e. I have an OU called "Clients" and one level under this OU there are multiple OUs , one for each client. i.e. CAS, ADI, PMA

I would like to get a list with the description of these sub OUs.
Following the previous example, the result would be: "Casio, Adidas, Puma"

I tried Get-ADOrganizationalUnit but I couldn't figure out a way of doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would this help you out:

```
$OU = 'OU=Europe,OU=World,DC=domain,DC=net'

Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase $OU -SearchScope Subtree -Filter * | 
     Select-Object DistinguishedName, Name
```

You can find information on how to use the CmdLet `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit` by typing:

```
help Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Example
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't, It is showing all the subOU names within the given OU. I just want the first level subOUs (the ones that are immedialy one level under the given OU) I should have specified that, my apologies. And I am also getting the actual parent OU listed. I don't want that.

Comment: I got it, Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase $OU -SearchScope Onelevel -Filter * |  Select-Object DistinguishedName, Name

Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome :) Usually, you can find the options in the help. Good work! The more you explore, the more you'll love to use PowerShell.